# ¿Como decidir si el color de las letras es blanco o negro dependiendo del fondo?

Tags: javascript

Quisiera saber como cambiar el color de las letras dinamicamente con JavaScript, asi como el `Color Picker de Google` por ejemplo cuando el fondo sea negro las letras blancas y viceversa.

Para buscar el `Color Picker de Google` solo busquen color picker en dicha pagina y sabrán a lo que me refiero.

Cualquier ayuda es aceptada tanto rangos de RGB o un plugin de JavaScript.

De antemano gracias por leer.

Comment: Revisa este link https://css-tricks.com/methods-contrasting-text-backgrounds/

Answer (score 1):

Hice un pequeño [Codepen](https://codepen.io/thunder01/pen/jQgKMx) respondiendo la pregunta gracias a la fuente de estas otras preguntas, es [este link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623838/rgb-to-hex-and-hex-to-rgb) se responde como obtener el RGB de un String Hexadecimal en [este otro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942878/how-to-decide-font-color-in-white-or-black-depending-on-background-color) se responde como decidir el color de la letra dependiendo del fondo, en este me encontré otro [Codepen](https://codepen.io/znak/pen/aOvMOd) en donde esta la formula usando JQuery.

Acoplando todas estas formulas obtuve el resultado esperado.

Si gustan pueden compararlo con el `Color Picker de Google.`